# Verify string format with given pattern

Tags: c++, performance, comparative-review

I'm implementing an auxiliary global function which has to check whether a given string has correct format (i.e., it begins with a letter and only contains letters, numbers or the "_" character).

This function, named `ok_tret`, will be used in the methods of a couple classes and will help ensure that the attributes are initialized with correct words and the rest of the methods are getting correct words as parameters.

The classes will be used in situations in which incorrect inputs are not frequent. They'll only happen when the user misspells the word, or by ignorance. So my guess is there will be two errors per read at worst.

My first `ok_tret` proposal returns a *bool* that tells us whether the given word is correct. This means we'll have to do the `cin` in the class method and then pass the word to the function. If there's error, then we'll have various function calls, until eventually the functions returns true.

```
const char *err4 = "ERROR. Init again.";

// Check correctness, return corresponding bool.
bool ok_tret(const string& nom) {
    if (not ((nom[0] >= 'a' and nom[0] <= 'z') or
        (nom[0] >= 'A' and nom[0] <= 'Z'))) {
        cout << err4 << endl;
        return false;
    } 
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < nom.length(); ++i) {
        if (not ((nom[i] >= '0' and nom[i] <= '9') or 
            (nom[i] >= 'A' and nom[i] <= 'Z') or 
            (nom[i] >= 'a' and nom[i] <= 'z') or nom[i] == '_')) {
                cout << err4 << endl;
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The next proposal also does the `cin`, so in order to get a correct word there's no need for various function calls.

```
// Check correctness and cin until nom contains a correct word. Iterative.
void ok_tret(string& nom) {
    bool P = true;
    while (P) {
        if ((nom[0] >= 'a' and nom[0] <= 'z') or 
            (nom[0] >= 'A' and nom[0] <= 'Z')) {
            for (unsigned int i = 1; P and i < nom.length(); ++i)
                if (not ((nom[i] >= '0' and nom[i] <= '9') or 
                    (nom[i] >= 'A' and nom[i] <= 'Z') or 
                    (nom[i] >= 'a' and nom[i] <= 'z') or nom[i] == '_')) 
                    P = false;
        } else P = false; 
        P = !P; 
        if (P) {
            cout << err4 << endl;
            cin >> nom;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally a recursive solution, obviously there will be multiple function calls:

```
// Check correctness and cin until nom contains a correct word. Recursive.
void ok_tret(string& nom) {
    if (not ((nom[0] >= 'a' and nom[0] <= 'z') or 
        (nom[0] >= 'A' and nom[0] <= 'Z'))) {
            cout << err4 << endl;
            cin >> nom;
            ok_tret(nom);
            return;
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < nom.length(); ++i) {
        if (not ((nom[i] >= '0' and nom[i] <= '9') or 
            (nom[i] >= 'A' and nom[i] <= 'Z') or 
            (nom[i] >= 'a' and nom[i] <= 'z') or nom[i] == '_')) {
                cout << err4 << endl;
                cin >> nom;
                ok_tret(nom);
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

**I wanted to know:**

1. Which proposal looks more natural?
2. Given the context in which the code will be used, there's no meaningful runtime difference between proposals. But... come on, which one would you choose and why?
3. If number of errors could be arbitrary (0 to a billion), which one would you choose and why?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I [changed the title](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/182247/revisions) so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._". Feel free to give it a different title if there is something more appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

I'd instead use the [`std::isalpha()`](https://devdocs.io/c/string/byte/isalpha) to check for the alphabets, and for the rest; use [`isalnum()`](https://devdocs.io/cpp/string/byte/isalnum) plus an **or** condition for the `_` character.

Another check, I'd put is whether the input's length is indeed \$ \gt 0 \$. The code then becomes:

```
// Check correctness, return corresponding bool.
bool ok_tret(const string& nom) {
    if (nom.length() < 1) {
        // handle null strings
        return false;
    }
    if (not (bool) std::isalpha(nom[0])) {
        cout << err4 << endl;
        return false;
    } 
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < nom.length(); ++i) {
        if (not ((bool) std::isalnum(nom[i]) or nom[i] == '_')) {
                cout << err4 << endl;
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: For single line code following an if statement you do not need braces, improving the clealiness of the code. Also why the C style cast to bool? Why not static cast?

Comment: Single line `if`s should always use braces to avoid coding errors -- what if in the future you want to add another line to the block? You may forget to add the braces, causing unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 9):

**Regular Expression Solution**

Firstly, this can be accomplished with regular expressions rather easily:

```
bool ok_tret(const std::string& nom){

    static const std::regex re{"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+$"};

    return std::regex_match(nom, re);
}
```

The advantage is obvious: compactness. We are making a single call to a function, `ok_tret` is basically acting as a wrapper function.

The problem with this some might say is readability: not everyone understands regular expressions, but that can be said of other language features like template metaprogramming and moreover there are many tools online to build your own regular expressions.

**Performance Considerations**

I tested both the regular expression function and your function, for a million strings, of length 100 characters, randomly distributed. Your function was 6% the total time for mine.

With `-O3`, it was 2.5% of the total time for the regular expression. So the more specific approach seems to be more easily optimised by the compiler.

This is to be expected since a specialised solution will run faster; regular expressions are coded to deal with virtually any matching conditions. However, I suspect this function won't be called as in my test conditions and the performance difference won't come into play.

---

Some obvious complaints with your code are not to use a `const char*`, go with,

```
constexpr char* err4{"ERROR. Init again."};
```

where you are using two modern C++ features: constant expressions and uniform initialisation.

Comment: Great. Could you elaborate a little bit on "regular expressions are coded to deal with virtually any matching conditions"?

Comment: I'm getting some compilation errors because of string not being a literal. Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123306/is-it-possible-to-use-stdstring-in-a-constexpr

Comment: What header file do you have to include to get `std::regex_match`? When did this become part of the standard library?

Comment: @Snowbody ‘regex.’

Comment: You might make it *as efficient* as hand-rolled code (after the first call) by constructing just one regex: `static const std::regex re{"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+$"}; return std::regex_match(nom, re);`.  That avoids overhead of parsing the regex and converting it to internal form (such as DFA) each time the function is called.  Becuse the `std::regex` constructor isn't declared `constexpr`, your compiler can't make that optimisation for you.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, just updated. From 3.5 to 6 percent.

Comment: I've added [another answer](/a/182327) showing my own performance measurement methodology and results - was too long for a comment.

Comment: Good answer but I would argue strongly that the readability of the regular expression is a *plus*, not a problem: It is unarguably **more readable** than OP’s version — by a wide margin. Obviously that requires that the reader knows regex. But that’s a more than reasonable requirement, in the same vein as requiring that programmers know basic arithmetic, bit operations, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Your first version is the closest to being in good programming style.

I don't like #3 because recursion's practical usefulness is limited. It leads to hard-to-understand code. I believe it is only taught to the degree it is in programming classes to force students to think. In nearly every case, the code can-- and should-- be rewritten to use iteration. It will be clearer, shorter, less error-prone, easier to read, and use less memory.

I don't like #2 because it is a tenet of programming that one ought to separate user interaction from the logic of the program. This is if you need to change how the program gets its data, you only have to change it in one place, without going through multiple functions. The processing functions should just process the input they're given as parameters (or member variables, for classes). It is actually cleaner this way. Don't worry about multiple functions; functions' actual cost is close to 0 with a decent compiler.

Anyway, a few comments:

```
const char *err4 = "ERROR. Init again.";
```

Why isn't this a `std::string`? You're using C++, so make use of its features.

```
void ok_tret(string& nom)
```

Is this a language other than English? I can't find any meaning of "tret" in wiktionary that makes sense here, which means it's probably an abbreviation or initialism. You really ought to write out the whole word; you don't get a bonus for making your function names cryptically short.

Also, why are you using `string` instead of `std::string`? [It's bad practice to have `using namespace std;`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

```
if (not ((nom[0] >= 'a' and nom[0] <= 'z') or
    (nom[0] >= 'A' and nom[0] <= 'Z'))) {
```

Use `std::isalpha()` instead. (you'll need to `#include <cctype>`)

```
for (unsigned int i = 1; i < nom.length(); ++i) {
```

Use an iterator. You should also become aware of about the new c++ range-based `for` syntax, available since 2011, though it's a little questionable to use here. It'd be something like `for(const char& c : nom.substr(1))`

```
            if (not ((nom[i] >= '0' and nom[i] <= '9') or 
                (nom[i] >= 'A' and nom[i] <= 'Z') or 
                (nom[i] >= 'a' and nom[i] <= 'z') or nom[i] == '_'))
```

Using `std::isalnum()` you can replace most of this, also in cctype.

Answer (score 6):

An addendum to [JNS's `std::regex` answer](/a/182262): we can compare two implementations for speed.  The first is a corrected version of the OP code (testing the string length and using `<cctype>` functions to work with character encodings that have non-contiguous alphabets), and the second is a simplified regexp function:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

bool v1(const std::string& nom)
{
    if (nom.size() == 0 || !std::isalpha(nom[0]))
        return false;
    for (auto c: nom)
        if (c != '_' && !std::isalnum(c))
            return false;
    return true;
}

bool v2(const std::string& nom)
{
    static const std::regex re{"[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*"};
    return std::regex_match(nom, re);
}
```

We can test both implementations for correctness, and compare their runtimes.

Here, we create one million strings of length 0-100 chars, alternating valid and invalid.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

static std::random_device rd;
static std::mt19937 gen{rd()};

template<typename T>
auto& pick_one(T&& s)
{
    auto dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<>{0, (int)s.size() - 1};
    return s[dist(gen)];
}

std::string example(bool valid)
{
    static const std::string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    static const std::string idchars = letters + "0123456789_";
    static const std::string others = "!@#$%^&*(){}?<>:+/,.;=-\\|'";

    static std::uniform_int_distribution<> length_dist{0, 100};
    std::string::size_type length = length_dist(gen);
    if (!length && valid) ++length;
    if (!length) return {};

    auto id = std::string(length, pick_one(letters));
    std::generate(id.begin()+1, id.end(), [] { return pick_one(idchars); });

    if (!valid)
        pick_one(id) = pick_one(others);

    return id;
}

int verify(const std::vector<std::string>& ids, bool (*f)(const std::string&))
{
    auto errs = 0;
    bool v = true;
    for (auto const s: ids)
        errs += (v=!v) != f(s);
    return errs;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> test_set;
    auto n = 1000000u;
    bool v = true;
    test_set.reserve(n);
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(test_set), n, [&v]{ return example(v=!v); });

    // Run through once each to reduce biases due to cache memory and branch prediction
    auto errs = verify(test_set, v1)
        + verify(test_set, v2);

    using Duration = std::chrono::duration<double, std::chrono::milliseconds::period>;

    auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    errs += verify(test_set, v1);
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    Duration time_1 = end - begin;

    begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    errs += verify(test_set, v2);
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    Duration time_2 = end - begin;

    std::cout << (time_2/time_1) << std::endl;
    return errs;
}
```

Without optimisation, I found that `v1` was about 10 times the speed of `v2`, but `gcc -O3` reduced the margin to about 5:1 or so.  This is still embarrassing for the regex implementation - we would expect it to be close to our hand-rolled implementation (particularly as we've made sure that it also respects locale).  I'd appreciate any comments that help explain the disparity.

Comment: It’s worth pointing out that the performance of the regex implementation is still embarrassing. Well-implemented regex engines without backreferences should be expected to reach hand-coded speed: there’s no good reason why they shouldn’t (this is an extremely well-researched problem with a known solution). And since backreferences make this impossible to achieve, the user needs to be able to choose whether to enable them. C++ regex are terrible. :-(

Answer (score 5):

I would use some standard library functions to help you out.

```
// Check correctness, return corresponding bool.
bool ok_tret(string const& nom) {
    if (not std::isalpha(nom[0])) {
        std::cout << err4 << "\n";
        return false;
    } 

    static constexpr char valid[] = "abcdef.......XYZ0123456789_";
    if (std::strspn(nom.c_str(), valid) != nom.size()) {
        std::cout << err4 << "\n";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't we use `std::isalnum`? Or is it uglier due to conversion to `unsigned char`?

Comment: @Incomputable `isalnum()` cant use it on the first part as we don't want numbers. The second part its much more optimized use `strspn()` as internally it builds a test table so each character is only tested once.

Comment: @LokiAstari Wouldn't `nom.find_first_not_of(valid)` be preferable here? And that way `valid` could be a `std::string` too.

Comment: @Snowbody That is even better. I forget all the built in string functions.

Answer (score 5):

All three versions have a common **bug**:

Accessing the first element of `nom` is undefined behaviour if the string is empty.  Check the `size()` of it before doing anything else!

---

All three versions have a problem with error output.

Firstly, error output should be separated from normal output, so use `std::cerr` rather than `std::cout` for these.  That allows piping the output of your program into another to work in the usual way.

Secondly, it can limit your future options if utility functions such as these produce their own output.  It's better to use the return value (or, in some cases, exceptions) to communicate with the calling code.  That allows you to use the function in a daemon (reporting via syslog) or in a GUI program (reporting via a message window), or to take other corrective action.